# WPF UI not updating when binding to StaticResource

Tags: wpf, binding, controls

I've followed the example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970451.aspx to the letter.

In my case I have a label with the Content bound to the Name property.

```
 <Label  Name="lblName" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=Name}"/>
```

There is a textbox and a button on the Page. The codebehind for the button is

```
Dim p As New Person
p.Name = txtbox1.Text
```

Stepping through the code I see the OnPropertyChanged being called and then the Setter with the correct value for personName. After it's run the label on the page is still at the original value. I think I'm missing something really simple but after much searching and trial and error can't get it working. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code behind is creating a *new* person, not using the instance in `myDataSource`.

```
'This creates a new instance - you need to set "myDataSource.Name" instead
Dim p As New Person
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed p.Name = txtbox1.Text to myDataSource.Name but that doesn't compile

Comment: I changed p.Name = txtbox1.Text to myDataSource.Name = txtbox1.Text but that doesn't compile
'myDataSource' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

myDataSource is defined in the XAML
   <Page.Resources>
         <src:Person x:Key="myDataSource" PName="Fred" />
    </Page.Resources>

Comment: Thank You! This works in the Click method
        Dim o As Object = Me.PageOne.Resources("myDataSource")
        o.PName = txtName.Text

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your constructor

`Me.DataContext = myDataSource`

Comment: I added that to the Page constructor, but it doesn't compile
'myDataSource' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. myDataSource is defined in the XAML <Page.Resources> <src:Person x:Key="myDataSource" PName="Fred" /> </Page.Resources>